# How are external ips supposed to work in OpenShift (4.x)?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, openshift

I'm looking for some help in understanding how [external ips](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-service-external-ip.html)
are supposed to work (specifically on OpenShift 4.4/4.5 baremetal).

- It looks like I can assign arbitrary external ips to a service
  regardless of the setting of `spec.externalIP.policy` on the `cluster`
  network. Is that expected?
- Once an external ip is assigned to a service, what's supposed to
  happen?  The openshift docs are silent on this topic. The [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips)
  say:

  > Traffic that ingresses into the cluster with the external
  > IP (as destination IP), on the Service port, will be routed to one
  > of the Service endpoints.

  Which suggests that if I (a) assign an externalip to a service and
  (b) configure that address on a node interface, I should be able to
  reach the service on the service port at that address, but that
  doesn't appear to work.

Poking around the nodes after setting up a service with an external ip, I don't see netfilter rules or anything else that would direct traffic for the external address to the appropriate pod.

I'm having a hard time findings docs that explain how all this is
supposed to operate.